# Bash script programming: how to match pattern in string?

Tags: grep, regex, text-processing

How I can get this whole value `7I45432ZX` from below lines:

```
PW*3434*453*256*PE*UB
PO*00*NE*7I4543
2ZX**20140617
PW*3434*453*256*PE*UB
PO*00*NE*7I4543
2ZX**20140617
```

This is the code I tried:

```
grep -oP 'PO.00.[A-Z][A-Z].\K[A-Z0-9_-]*' < file.txt
```

I have this code above however,the generated output is only this **`7I4543`** and not the whole **`7I45432ZX`**, which is suppose to be my expected output. Is there something I had to modify or add after `.\K` to get the whole value?

Comment: ...so despite my [suggested edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/296873) to remove the `Perl` tag having been rejected, I would like to point out that neither was the OP related to `Perl`, nor is `Perl` required to provide a solution.

Comment: My off-topic flag was also denied. This question is surrounded by a strange aura.

Comment: Well, this is not OT.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following oneliner:

```
$ cat file.txt | perl -e 's/\s//g && print "$_\n" for join("", <>) =~ /\*([\w\s]+)\*\*/g'
7I45432ZX
7I45432ZX
```

I'm basically looking for a pattern between a star `*` and 2 stars `**`. Once found, I'm just removing the spaces/carriage returns before printing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 awk -F "*" '{ if ($1 == "PO") { lastTok = $(NF); getline; print lastTok "" $1;}}' input.txt
```

awk use "*" as separator and print last field of line that start with PO followed by first field of next line.

The output is:

```
7I45432ZX
7I45432ZX
```

If you have file in dos format, you should use [dos2unix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/dos2unix.1.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

Through `grep` and `sed`:

```bsh
grep -oPz '7I4543$\n^2ZX' file |sed '$!N;s/\n//'
7I45432ZX
7I45432ZX
```

`grep` patterns `7I4543` and `2ZX` and everything between them in multiple lines. `$` in grep command points to end of line and `^` points start of line.

`sed` joins every pair of lines to one linear. `$` points the current line, `N` points to next line. then replace/remove newline `\n` between that lines.

```bsh
-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.

-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)

-z, --null-data
      Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII 
      NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option 
      can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```

Possible other `grep`s:

```bsh
$ grep -oPz '7I4543$(^2ZX|\n)+'
$ grep -oPz '7I4543$\s^2ZX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pcregrep:

```
sudo apt-get install pcregrep
```

and then run:

```
pcregrep -oM "PO.00.[A-Z][A-Z].\K[A-Z0-9_-].*\s+.*\*" < file.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/\*\*/\n/g'
```

Output:

```
7I45432ZX
7I45432ZX
```

Here's the explanation of what the script does. First of all I had to make your original script read across linefeeds and then after that it would output the result on two separate lines unless I made it write across linefeeds too. The last part of the script `sed -e 's/\*\*/\n/g'` puts a linefeed after each delimiter as requested by the author of the question in a comment to this answer.

Comment: Note that if line endings are CR/LF (Windows), it won't work (the `tr` part of your command)

Comment: @karen&sylvian: I'm just making the code more generic so that I can use it whether the file has * as a delimiter or not (since in my e.g. file I use *). I use your code but with some changes:  pcregrep -oM "PO.00.[A-Z][A-Z].\K[A-Z0-9_-\s]+" < file.txt. It gets the expected output then but now with new line. How can I consolidate those values? Or how to omit the new line so that values will be consolidated? Thanks.

Comment: @user74775 Here is the revised code with that works whether the file has * as a delimiter or not and gives the expected output nicely formatted on one line: `pcregrep -oM "PO.00.[A-Z][A-Z].\K[A-Z0-9_-\s]+" < file.txt | tr -d '\n' && echo`. The string `| tr -d '\n'` does the formatting and the `&& echo` adds a linefeed at the end of the output.

Comment: @karel:definitely it truly works, but another problem  is when I add another contains in my file like I did above, the output is this: 7I45432ZX7I45432ZX. Can you help me again how to make them output like this: 7I45432ZX (with new line as there separator) 7I45432ZX where the next output will not be compress to the first one?

Comment: @user74775 As you requested, I edited my answer to make it output like this: 7I45432ZX (with new line as their separator) 7I45432ZX where the next output will not be compressed to the first line of the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install `Perl` or anything else and want to go with good old standard coomand line tools, you can use something along the lines of:

```
sed '1 d
2 s/^PO\*00\*[A-Z][A-Z]\*\([A-Z0-9_-]*\)$/\1/
3 s/^\([A-Z0-9_-]*\)\*\*.*$/\1/' < file.txt
```

This assumes that

- your file contains 3 lines. If your file contains 5 lines with lines 1, 3 and 5 containing the relevant info, you'll have to replace `2` by `3` and `3` by `5` and add `2 d` and `4 d` commands on additional lines by themselves;
- you can live with the line feed in the output. If that is not okay for you, pipe the output to `tr` like so: `| tr -d "\n\r"`

[Edit]

- The `sed` part also assumes that you have `UN*X` text lines. Also, there seems to be a dispute how strict the pattersn should be. I feel the OP suggested a certain degree of strictness. Either way, the `sed` patterns can be easily adjusted to accept `DOS` line endings, e.g. by ending in `\r*$`.

Comment: Perl is installed by default, nothing to install (See the 14.04 [manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest)).Note that if line endings are CR/LF (Windows), it won't work (the `tr` part of your command) and it's not really reliable to hardcode the lines containing data. I'm sure `sed` can parse multiline strings as well

Comment: @SylvainPineau What about the `tr` part wouldn't work?

Comment: Try to convert your input file to Windows line endings (\r\n). Both the sed and tr commands return erroneous patterns

Comment: @SylvainPineau Agreed for the `sed` part, but not for `tr`. `tr` uses a set.

Comment: You're right, `tr` was ok and `sed` was not.

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU awk,

```
$ awk -v RS="PO" '/^\*/{gsub(/^.*\*/,"",$1); gsub(/\*.*$/,"",$2); print $1$2}' file
7I45432ZX
7I45432ZX
```